# Update query performace with 1M+ rows table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables

`stock_details` (1M+ records ) with fields

```
billid

itemid

groupid

qty
```

`stock_details` indexes `index1` (`itemid`,`billid`) and `index2`(`itemid`)

`itemmaster` (10K+ records) with fields

```
itemid

groupid
```

`itemmaster` has indexes `index1` (`itemid`) and `index2` (`groupid`)

Below query takes few mins to complete. I don't think its normal. There may be only few records or zero records which actually gets updated. I think I have all indexes in place for the query

```
UPDATE Stock_details A,Db2.ItemMaster B 
SET A.Groupid=B.Groupid
WHERE A.Itemid=B.itemID AND A.Groupid<>B.GroupId
```

Ran an Explain on the select query

```
EXPLAIN SELECT A.groupid FROM Stock_details A,db2.ItemMaster B 
WHERE A.Itemid=B.itemID AND A.Groupid<>B.GroupId
```

and the result is here
https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0HTS.png

Answer (score 1):

The "not" portion of the query can't be indexed effectively, so each row must be scanned.

I imagine this is something you have to run periodically (or else you wouldn't care how long it took).  One thing you could to is keep track of the time last run, and only consider rows updated since that time.

Comment: its not run periodically. But in my application there is an Optimize option where it checks for any data errors (i dont have foreign key constraints set) missing fields etc.. It is run with lot of other queries. so alltogether it takes lot of time to complete. Is there any other way i can re-write this query?

Comment: I think the answer is no.  But if you are willing to look outside this query there might be something you can do.  For example update the groupids in both tables simultaneously so you don't need this checking.  Track some timestamps, as I suggested, in order to make the checking more efficient (of course you would have to add a field, and an index for that, but tracking create/update time is so standard - you should almost always do that anyway.

Comment: got it. actually the chance for mismatch is minimal. i could give timestamp a try becuase it already exists in the table. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure.. but try this and see...

1) index on itemid and group id togethewr might help

2)

UPDATE 
(select A.Groupid,B.Groupid as Groupids  from
 Stock_details A,Db2.ItemMaster B 
  WHERE A.Itemid=B.itemID 
  AND A.Groupid<>B.GroupId) k
set k.Groupid=k.Groupids

Comment: As the stock table is very insert-intensive. i wanted to reduce the indexes there. but by adding Groupid into index2 as (itemid,groupid) made good progress in select query but not in update query .i could still use it i think by using a temp table. thanks. The above update query doesnt seem work. it says "The target table k of the UPDATE is not updatable".